# Read SPSS file into R, the data format for date is wrong, and generate more variable

Tags: r

I have tried using *spss.get* from Hmisc.
Here is my code:

```
    install.packages("Hmisc")
    library(Hmisc)
    mydata <- spss.get("C:\\good good study\\comscore\\purchase.sav", use.value.labels = TRUE)
```

the output is shown with warning message which is as follows:

```
> mydata <- spss.get("C:\\good good study\\comscore\\purchase.sav", use.value.labels = TRUE)
Warning messages:
1: In read.spss(file, use.value.labels = use.value.labels, to.data.frame = to.data.frame,  :
C:\good good study\comscore\purchase.sav: Unrecognized record type 7, subtype 14 encountered in system file
2: In read.spss(file, use.value.labels = use.value.labels, to.data.frame = to.data.frame,  :
C:\good good study\comscore\purchase.sav: Unrecognized record type 7, subtype 18 encountered in system file
```

My initial date in spss is as follow：
[date in spss is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bbLi.jpg)

However， when I use spss.get in R, the data for date becomes garbled:
[date become garbled in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7HDw.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a number of seconds from some specific time what you see in R. You can convert it to date or time. For example:

```
z <- c(10485849601, 10477641600, 10561104000, 10562745600)
as.POSIXct(z, origin="1582-10-14", tz="GMT")
```

The value `"1582-10-14"` for the `origin` is taken from the SPSS Statistics Base manual:

> Internally, all date and time format values are stored as a number of seconds: date formats (e.g., DATE, ADATE, SDATE, DATETIME) are stored as the number of seconds since October 14, 1582; time formats (TIME, DTIME) are stored as a number of seconds that represents a time interval (e.g., 10:00:00 is stored internally as 36000, which is 60 seconds x 60 minutes x 10 hours).

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/base/syn_date_and_time_date_time_formats.html

For time values probably the best option is to use the `chron` library. See the example:

```
require(chron)
y <- c(58130, 10981)
chron(times. = y / (24*60*60))
```

Have you tried the `haven` package for reading the SPSS data?

Comment: Thanks  for your answer. I have convert the  data for date into correct format using your code. Further,  I want to ask how to convert the data for time into correct format?

Comment: Thanks for your code @djhurio. How do you know the value of `origin` option?

Comment: @jgarces, I got this information from the SPSS Statistics manual: "Internally, all date and time format values are stored as a number of seconds: date formats (e.g., DATE, ADATE, SDATE, DATETIME) are stored as the number of seconds since October 14, 1582;" https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/base/syn_date_and_time_date_time_formats.html